# Need help on this SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, string

Here is the question:

```
+--------------+
Ships          |
+--------------+
Duke of north  |
---------------+
Prince of Wales|
---------------+
Baltic         |
---------------+
```

I need to replace all characters between the first and the last spaces (excluding these spaces) by symbols of an asterisk (*). The number of asterisks must be equal to number of replaced characters.

for example: "Duke of North" must be replaced as "Duke ** North",
I managed to cut the "of" from "Duke of North" but am really stuck with the replacement part, can any one give me some ideas, am learning SQL in MS SQL Server 2005, please help.
I dont need the exact answer just give me some ideas,

```
select 
case when charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1) > 0 
     then substring(ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1,((charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1)) - (charindex(' ',ship,1))))
end "Replace"
from 
outcomes
```

This is not a homework question, am learning SQL.

Comment: So if "Duke of North" becomes "Duke ** North", what are you expecting for "Baltic" and "Ships"?

Comment: CHARINDEX will return the position of the first space character. You'd have to use the function twice, using the first instance location as the starting point for the second check...

Comment: This is commonly handled by a regex replace, which on SQL Server 2005+ requires the use of a CLR function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
isnull(case when charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1) > 0 
     then substring(ship,1,charindex(' ',ship,1))+space(1)+replace(substring(ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1,((charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1)) - (charindex(' ',ship,1)))),substring(ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1,((charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1)) - (charindex(' ',ship,1)))),replicate('*',len(substring(ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1,(charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1)) - (charindex(' ',ship,1))))))+space(1)+substring(ship,(charindex(' ',ship,(charindex(' ',ship,1))+1)),(len(ship)))
end,ship) "Replace"
from 
outcomes
```

After a long try got the answer on my own!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ship NOT LIKE '% % %' THEN ship
ELSE
LEFT(ship,CHARINDEX(' ',ship)) + 
      REPLICATE('*', LEN(ship)- CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(ship)) - CHARINDEX(' ',ship)) +
      RIGHT(ship, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(ship)))
END
FROM outcomes
```

If you commonly need to Select the data in this modified form you could add a computed column as below.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.outcomes ADD
    displayName  AS CASE WHEN ship NOT LIKE '% % %' THEN ship
ELSE
LEFT(ship,CHARINDEX(' ',ship)) + 
      REPLICATE('*', LEN(ship)- CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(ship)) - CHARINDEX(' ',ship)) +
      RIGHT(ship, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(ship)))
END PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of learning SQL is to learn to identify tasks that should *not* be performed in SQL. This should be left as part of the display logic, and should stay out of the database engine.

Comment: What do you mean? I use SQL all the time to see if dates lie within a range.

Comment: So you've never had to update a column value to replace text?

Comment: Interesting answer. Think of an enterprise database where the data is shared by many applications and users with varying levels of access. I can see a case for providing partially obscured data via `VIEW`s to users who are compentent enough to write SQL queries yet do have the rights to view confidential information but who need visual feedback on whether they are looking at the correct data.